# Where is the "Build Active Architecture Only" flag in Xcode 4.5.1?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm sorry because it's not really a strictly programming question but I'm going crazy and google is not being friendly in this.

Can someone explain to me like I'm five where I can set that flag for Release?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Project Navigator** (Command+1) select your project.
The Editor will now show your project settings.

The **Build Active Architecture Only** setting is available on Project level in the
**Architectures** section (filter for e.g. '*arch*', for best results select **All** instead of the **Basic** option selected in the screenshot).

The setting can be adjusted individually for the Debug and Release targets.

[image]